# How to copy the output directory of one projects into a subfolder under the output directory of an another one?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have 2 projects and I with the build I want to copy the whole output directory of the project A (A\bin[Debug|Release]\net[WhatEver]\*) under the output directory of project B into a subfolder, like B\bin[Debug|Release]\net[WhatEver]\A\.

I could copy after build with a post build event the output of A into a temp directory and at build of B copy that temp directory in an another post build event, but is there a better solution?

An extra expectation is that if A changes B rebuilds automatically.

Comment: Whats the purposes of this? Is A a dependency of B. Then B won't find A in a subfolder just by itself without help.

Comment: Post-Build event is likely the only "place" to put it in a standard DEV environment using VS.

Comment: @Ralf Project A is e.g. an exe, a tool that B uses, with his own dlls

Comment: @lidqy I am afraid, yes :/ Thx!